# Licensing for a site with many subdomains

Tags: subdomain, kentico

My company has a Kentico v11 site with 6 subdomains. We are planning on adding about 5 more in the near future. The site is made up of one Kentico instance and one set of pages to be served. We simply change the styling of the site based on the subdomain, and we filter the data to only show the appropriate information per subdomain. Up until now, we have been getting a new Kentico license for each subdomain but, that is getting a little burdensome. My question is this: Do we need to get a separate license for each subdomain? If we don't, then how do I avoid the licensing error when I try to access a new subdomain on the site?

Thanks in advance for whatever information you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already following the correct procedure, generating a new license for each subdomain.

I would highly recommend that you discuss anything license related directly with Kentico Xperience sales (**sales@xperience.io**) or with your account manager.

Kentico 11 support ends on [November 30, 2021](https://xperience.io/product/roadmap/product-support-lifecycle), I would recommend upgrading your installation to Kentico 12 so you have extended support through fall 2023.